# Java input Exception from file

Tags: java, exception, file-io, java.util.scanner

This is a programming project for my introductory Java class.  I am supposed to run the program from the Terminal using information input from a text file.

I can set that up but it keeps throwing a No Such Element Exception at me.  The exception comes during the second round of the while loop.  I have attempted to place all the inputs on the same line and I tried adding an extra line between each pair.  I have also tried removing the extra input.nextLine().

Here is the exception:

```
Enter the price or -1 to quit: $
Is this purchase a pet? y/n:
Enter the price or -1 to quit: $Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
at DAG_PetDiscounterTester.main(DAG_PetDiscounterTester.java:33)
```

The file input are:
23.56
n
178.97
n
395.88
y
.98
n
1.97
n
57.89
y
12.33
n
-1

The section of code that is throwing the exception is:

```
  while((done == false) && (nItems < ARRAY_SIZE))
  //While loop keeps the program going until user enters sentinel or array is full
  {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   //Create a scanner

     System.out.printf("Enter the price or -1 to quit: $");
     price = input.nextDouble();
     //Inform user of required input and read it, assigning it to price

     while((price <= 0) && (price != -1))
     {
     System.out.printf("Enter the price or -1 to quit: $");
     price = input.nextDouble();
     }
     //If input is incorrect, continue to prompt until it is

     if(price == SENTINEL)   //If statement to check for sentinel
     {
        done = true;   //Changing boolean value ends the program
     }
     else  //If the program's not done, continue
     {
        input.nextLine(); //Clears newline character after price input

        System.out.printf("Is this purchase a pet? y/n: ");
        pet = input.nextLine();
        //Informs user of next information needed and assigns input to pet boolean

        while((!pet.equals("Y")) && (!pet.equals("y")) && (!pet.equals("N")) && (!pet.equals("n")))
        //Verifies user input
        {
           System.out.printf("Is this purchase a pet? y/n: ");
           pet = input.nextLine();
           //If input is incorrect, continue to prompt until it is
        }

        if((pet.equals("Y")) || (pet.equals("y")))
        //Decision statement determines what value to assign to pet boolean
        {
           isPet[nItems] = true;
        }

        else
        {
           isPet[nItems] = false;
        }

        prices[nItems] = price; //Assigns current item's price to prices array
        nItems++;   //Increments items counter to track number of items in the arrays
     }
  }
```

It specifically occurs at price = input.nextDouble().

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javadocs for Scanner say this about the `nextDouble()` method:

> Throws:
>
> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Float
>   regular expression, or is out of range
>
> NoSuchElementException - if the input is exhausted
>
> IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

This error is saying that there is not a double to grab with the method.

The issue comes from the Scanner looking at that line that contains just 'n' and being asked to fetch a double from that line, but one does not exist.

To prevent this you can do:

```
if(input.hasNextDouble()){
    price = input.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: That worked to get past that segment of code but now it presents an exception saying "no line found."  In addition, the next segment asking whether or not the item is a pet falls through to the verification line.

Comment: That worked to get past that line of code but now it presents an exception saying "no line found."  In addition, the next segment asking whether or not the item is a pet falls through to the verification statements, asking twice in a row, whether or not I use a line to clear the scanner.  When I run the program from jGrasp with keyboard input it works correctly, not falling through.  At this point, there's no time left to solve it so I will have to submit it as-is.  Thank you for your help.